# Batch modifying text at specific line

Tags: batch-file, text, batch-processing

I should:

1) remove a whole line which is like

`HYDRAULICS blabla`

I thought to use

```
find /V "HYDRAULICS"....>path\file.ext
```

but in the file.ext it is written also the not needed

`---------- path\file.ext`

2) add, before lines which start with   `IF`    , a line containg the short phrase  `RULE 1`    (the first time,    `RULE 2` the second and so on).
I have the text

```
[RULES]
;Text
;-----------------------------
IF TANK T1421 LEVEL BELOW 1 THEN PUMP PT395&395dn STATUS IS OPEN                                     
IF TANK T1421 LEVEL ABOVE 3 THEN PUMP PT395&395dn STATUS IS CLOSED                                   
IF TANK T395 LEVEL BELOW 1 THEN PUMP PFALDA395&T395 STATUS IS OPEN                                   
IF TANK T395 LEVEL ABOVE 4 THEN PUMP PFALDA395&T395 STATUS IS CLOSED
```

but I want it to become

```
[RULES]
;Text
;-----------------------------
RULE 1
IF TANK T1421 LEVEL BELOW 1 THEN PUMP PT395&395dn STATUS IS OPEN                                     
RULE 2
IF TANK T1421 LEVEL ABOVE 3 THEN PUMP PT395&395dn STATUS IS CLOSED                                   
RULE 3
IF TANK T395 LEVEL BELOW 1 THEN PUMP PFALDA395&T395 STATUS IS OPEN                                   
RULE 4
IF TANK T395 LEVEL ABOVE 4 THEN PUMP PFALDA395&T395 STATUS IS CLOSED
```

Comment: Your point `2)` is not clear.

Comment: The post has been updated with more information, and many thanks for sharing your knowledge @foxidrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part `2)` this uses a mixture of old and new techniques - the input file is `file.txt` and the output file is `newfile.txt`

It can be simplified by used delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
del "%temp%\counter.txt" 2>nul
(
for /f "eol=| usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
   for /f  %%b in ("%%a") do ( if /i "%%b"=="IF" echo .>>"%temp%\counter.txt"
           for /f %%c in ('find /c "." ^<"%temp%\counter.txt" ') do echo RULE %%c
   )
echo %%a
)
)>"newfile.txt"
del "%temp%\counter.txt" 2>nul
```

This is a reformatted section - which Sandra seemed to say was more readable.

```
@echo off
del "%temp%\counter.txt" 2>nul
(
for /f "eol=| usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
   for /f  %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if /i "%%b"=="IF" (
          echo .>>"%temp%\counter.txt"
             for /f %%c in ('find /c "." ^<"%temp%\counter.txt" ') do echo RULE %%c
       )
   )
echo %%a
)
)>"newfile.txt"
del "%temp%\counter.txt" 2>nul
```

Comment: What is the `eol=|` for?

Comment: @aschipfl  the `eol` character defaults to `;` and all lines starting with `;` will disappear - and there are some of those.  I just took a punt and made it a pipe character instead - but any lines starting with the pipe character will disappear instead.

Comment: The solutions you have given work perfectly, but I can't mark them both. @foxidrive

Comment: I found adding () brackets after IF useful, in order to avoid the possibility that the `echo RULE %%c` command was repeated. @foxidrive

Comment: @foxidrive, what about specifying a delimiter as `eol`, e. g., a space (a default delimiter)?

Comment: @aschipfl I don't follow what you mean.  Sandra, is the reformatted code above what you meant?

Comment: @foxidrive, I meant specifying `eol=#` when `delims=#` for instance; I experimented a bit and found that `delims` seems to be processed before `eol`, so any leading delimiter is not regarded by `eol`... anyway, this won't work for the code here obviously as _no_ delimiter is given (`delims=`), so sorry for confusion...

Answer (score 0):

The extra line doesn't appear when redirection is used.

```
find /V "HYDRAULICS" <"filein.txt" >"path\file.ext"
```

Comment: The solutions you have given work perfectly, but I can't mark them both. @foxidrive